# could context switch cause stack overflow?

Tags: c, memory-management

Since each thread has its own stack, what would happen on the following situation?

1. Thread 1 make a very deep recursion call
2. Context switch to thread 2, thread 2 grows a large amount of memory on heap
3. Context switch back to thread 1.

After step 3, could there be a collision between stack and heap? When a new chunk on heap is allocated, would it check against every stack?

Comment: The classical model of "the stack grows down towards the heap, overflows when they meet" doesn't work so cleanly for multithreading. The reason is simple, there are multiple stacks. If you have virtual memory and paging, the usual solution is to allocate a "guard page" that causes an exception when accessed below each stack.

Comment: Context switching includes pushing the context somewhere -- possibly the stack, possibly a thread descriptor, so the answer to the question is implementation-specific. If to the stack and you're near the end, then yes.

Comment: I'm fairly sure "the stack grows towards the heap" has been wrong for a long time - as in, it was probably true in MS-DOS and maybe Windows 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no bugs and logical memory translation with page protection:

1) Memory is allocated for the stack and memory is allocated for the heap. There is no memory that can be heap or stack.

2) Thread 1's stack will not collide with the heap.

3) It is possible that Thread 1 may need to expand its stack and that the growth of heap caused by Thread 2 would prevent that.